# How do I create a zoom transition in Premiere Elements 9?

Tags: video, video-editor

Could you tell me how do I zoom in Adobe Premiere Elements 9? And I mean a slow zoom transition, not a non-transitioning zoom that "jumps" into zoom from one frame to the other.

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you included a link to an example (youtube or like) of what you are exactly looking for, and another link to the "non-transitioning zoom that "jumps" into zoom from one frame to the other."

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but here's what I use. Right-click on the piece being edited. (I usually view them in Timeline rather than Sceneline.) Choose "Show Properties." The important property for this purpose is Motion. Click on the little clock at the right end of the Motion heading. That will show you arrows where you can go forward and back, to see what keyframes you have set. (You can also right-click on the image and choose Show Clip Keyframes, but what you see is not necessarily very informative.) Add keyframes at the beginning and end of a clip, for Position, Scale, and Scale Width. (To add keyframes, click on the diamond, not the arrows, under the Motion clock.) If the little dot on the Timeline disappears (assuming you have selected Show Clip Keyframes), that means you turned the keyframe off, not on. Arrow back and forth to make sure your keyframes have been added for each of those three parameters. Now go somewhere in the middle of the clip and drag your image around in the viewing window and/or use the Motion sliders. Get your image where you want it and add those same three kinds of keyframes there too. Now, optionally, click on the camera picture, at the corner of the viewing window, and add a still image of your zoomed frame. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean but I you can get a zooming transition by adding keyframes to the scale and opacity property.

if you scale it up as you turn the opacity down it should look like a zoom and transisiton.